# Syntax error on token "int", invalid ClassTypec

Tags: java

wondering if someone can quickly help me with this error "Syntax error on token "int", invalid ClassType" In java. I'm programming a game, it currently has 3 class files.

Here's my code:

```
package com.cmnatic.reborn.gui;

public class Bitmap {
public final int width;
public final int height;
public final int[] pixels;

public Bitmap(int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    pixels = new int(width*height);
}
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to create an array? Use `[]`. Is it meant to be a 2d array? Read a tutorial on arrays in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This...

```
pixels = new int(width*height);
```

Isn't how arrays are initialised, the compiler thinks your are trying to create a new `Object`, `int` isn't a object, it's a primitive (special inbuilt type)

Try using...

```
pixels = new int[width*height];
```

Instead